# How to use abort method with flask?

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I would like to write the second code but I'm not sure of the merit of the first code. Would anyone please tell me the advantage of the first code? Also, can I write the code like the second one instead of the first one?

The first sample that I'm not sure of the advantages and I avoid writing this way:

```
  if not users:
        abort(401, {"error_message": "user_id is not defined."})
        return user_id, custmer_id
```

The second sample I would like to use

```
   if not users:
        return jsonify({"error_message": "user_id is not defined."}), 401
```

Comment: Not a full answer to the question, but maybe noticable: `The better solution than using abort to signal errors for invalid API usage is to implement your own exception type and install an error handler for it that produces the errors in the format the user is expecting.` from http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/apierrors/

Comment: what do you mean by  the format the user is expecting ? What is the format the user is expecting?

Comment: Have you read the provided link? `One of the first things that developers run into is the realization that the builtin exceptions are not expressive enough`. That's why it's okay to not use `abort`. But it's still not a full answer to your question, so it's simply a comment, hopefully a little bit helpful, at least.

Comment: Yes it’s useful. Thank you, but i’m curious of why the first code return user_id and custmoer_id in the first code when it uses aboard method.